# How do I find out which question, that I had answered and for which I received an upvote, was deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

Yesterday, I had a 100 answers in my answer list, today it's 99. Since I haven't deleted any of my own answers recently, I am assuming a question was deleted and so were all the answers to that question (including up-voted ones).

It's driving me a bit crazy that one of my answers has disappeared and I don't even know which one. Is there any way I can find out what was deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to [your reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4714/abbas?tab=reputation) -> click on *show removed posts*. It will show you your removed answers and questions with reputation changes. But you can not search for deleted posts from other pages. (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/search etc..)

Comment: True, but if he didn't get any upvotes on the answer it won't show there.

Comment: Thanks, I see that my assumption was incorrect. The question is still there, but my upvoted answer was deleted (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608625/convert-ms-sql-server-database-mdf-file-to-mysql-through-phpmyadmin/8608913#8608913). Is there anyway I can find out why the answer was deleted?

Comment: @Abbas - We can not directly find the reason behind the deletion of our post. But if you want to know it you can ask a new question here. But remember no one like ranting here. So ask it constructively. Also specify if you just want to find the reason or you want to undelete it.

Comment: Great, doing that. I definitely want it undeleted, I think I gave a good technical answer to a relevant questions.